# Rails 4 Devise flash error message not showing in all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

i am using Devise gem in my app and i want to show the devise error message in the flash

i have done this

**devise_helper.rb**

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return '' if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    html = <<-HTML
    <div class="alert alert-error alert-danger"> <button type="button"
    class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
      #{messages}
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

I am using login and sign up page in the same file as sessions/new.html.erb.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <div class="logmod__tab-wrapper">
        <div class="logmod__tab lgm-1">
          <div class="logmod__heading">
            <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your personal details <strong>to create an acount</strong></span>
          </div>
          <div class="logmod__form">

            <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
              <div class="sminputs">

                <div class="input full">
                  <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                  <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'string optional', :id => 'user-email', :placeholder => 'Email' %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="sminputs">
                <div class="input string optional">
                  <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                  <%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'string optional', :id => 'user-pw', :placeholder => 'Password' %>

                </div>
                <div class="input string optional">
                  <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat">Repeat password *</label>
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'string optional', :id => 'user-pw-repeat', :placeholder => 'Repeat Password' %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="simform__actions">
                <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'sumbit' %>
                <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By creating an account you agree to our <a class="special" href="#" target="_blank" role="link">Terms & Privacy</a></span>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="logmod__alter">
            <div class="logmod__alter-container">

            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>

      <%#= render "companies/shared/links" %>
        </div>
        <div class="logmod__tab lgm-2">
          <div class="logmod__heading">
            <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                <%= devise_error_messages! %>
          <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your email and password <strong>to sign in</strong></span>
          </div>
          <div class="logmod__form">
            <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
              <div class="sminputs">
                <div class="input full">
                  <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                  <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'string optional', :id => 'user-email', :placeholder => 'Email' %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="sminputs">
                <div class="input full">
                  <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => 'string optional', :id => 'user-pw', :placeholder => 'Password' %>
                  <span class="hide-password">Show</span>
                </div>
                <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                    <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
                      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
                    </div>
                <% end -%>
              </div>
              <div class="simform__actions">
                <%= f.submit "Log in", :class => 'sumbit', :name => 'commit' %>
                <span class="simform__actions-sidetext"><%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name), :class => 'special' %><br /></span>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="logmod__alter">
            <div class="logmod__alter-container">

            </div>
          </div>
            <% end %>
```

i am showing error msg from a jquery plugin call jquery growl

**layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<% if key == 'notice' %>
        <script>
          $.growl.notice({ message: "<%= value %>" });

      </script>
    <% elsif key == 'error' || key == 'alert' %>
     <script>

        $.growl.error({ message: "<%= value %>" });
        </script>
    <% end %>

      <!--<div class="alert alert-<%#= key %>"><%#= value %></div>-->
  <% end %>
```

the problem i am facing is while in the login tab i am able to show flash message but when i try to enter the already taken email in the sign up form, it renders a new page with no css but showing the flash message and not showing the flash message i am giving in the **application.html.erb** through jquery growl